# Ошибка в чтении строк

Tags: java, строки, клавиатура, ввод

Интересует ваше мнение по поводу сложившейся ситуации. Суть моей программы в том, что пользователь вводит сначала количество вводимых его  строк, а потом заполняет каждую, далее у меня идет работа с первым элементом в каждой вводимой его строке. Проблема заключается в том, что не успев ввести 1-ю строку, программа сразу запрашивает следующую, а после - выбивает ошибки.

```
System.out.print("Введите количество строк: ");

    if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        n = scanner.nextInt();
    } else {
       System.out.print("Введены некорректные данные!");
       return;
    }

    String[] strings = new String[n];`
```

Здесь пользователь вводит количество вводимых строк

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        System.out.printf((i+1)+ " ");

        strings[i] = scanner.nextLine();


    }
```

А в strings[i] - записываются все элементы каждой строки (как по идее оно должно быть)

```
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       char a = strings[i].charAt(0);

        if (Character.isLetter(strings[i].charAt(0))) {

           if (equals(a)){

               glas.append(strings[i]+" ");
           }
           else {

               neglas.append(strings[i]+" ");

           }

        }
        else {

            nebuk.append(strings[i]+" ");


        }

public static boolean equals(char obj) { 
  String letterglas = "aouie"; 
  for (int i = 0; i < letterglas.length(); i++) { 
    if (letterglas.charAt(i) == obj) { 
      return true; 
    } 
  }
  return false; 
}
```

А здесь идет уже работа с первым элементом в каждой строке, именно тут компилятор ругался на ошибку, возможно чем-то поможет для ее выявления. 
Важно чтобы пользователь мог записывать не только набор букв, но и пробельные символы, при том, чтобы слово после пробела воспринималось программой на той же строке, в которой пишутся другие символы.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `equals(a)` - что равно `а`?

Comment: а - первый символ в каждой строке

Comment: equals(a) - эта строчка не должна компилироваться, если у вас статик контекст. Наверное стоит заменить на a == 'a'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В строке

```
if (equals(a)){
```

вызов `equals` висит в воздухе.

```
if (a.equals('a')) {
  ...
```

Судя по названиям `glas`/`neglas`:

```
string vowels = "аеёиоуыэюя";
...
if (vowels.indexOf(a) != -1) { // a - гласная буква
  ...
```

---

В `strings[0]` у Вас пустая строка. Добавьте перед циклом

```
scanner.nextLine(); // добавьте эту строчку

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  System.out.printf((i+1)+ " ");
  strings[i] = scanner.nextLine();
}
```

Таким образом, прежде чем начать считывать строки, Вы считываете конец строки, который был введен пользователем после числа `n`.

А в цикле неплохо бы делать проверку

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  if (string[i].length() == 0)
    continue;

  char a = strings[i].charAt(0);
  ...
```

Comment: equals в моем случае - это моя функция, которая никак не связана с библиотечной

Comment: @MaxSquirrel В таком случае, на какой строке кода ошибка, и какой текст этой ошибки?

Comment: ошибка в том, что как только я компилирую свой код, то вместо того, чтобы в первую строку с клавиатуры написать символы, программа сразу перескакивает на 2-ю строчку, а как только я заполняю по требованиям все строки выбивает ошибку в строке
        char a = strings[i].charAt(0);

Comment: @MaxSquirrel Вы можете еще сто раз написать фразу "выбивает ошибку"? Текст ошибки сюда скопировать Вам не дает моральный кодекс советского разведчика?

Comment: Рассмешили вы меня, думал так проще будет понять проблему. Вот ошибка Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0

Comment: @MaxSquirrel Я так и думал ). Смотрите дополнение в ответе.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, заработало!

Comment: @MaxSquirrel На здоровье. Успехов!